# adding two styles to a button in windows store app using xaml and c#

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps

I want to use two styles for a button in windows store app using XAML and c# , on click event want to change the style . how can i do that ? i am trying to add resources but unable to get any result . please help me about this .

here is my app.xaml

```
<Application
    x:Class="App1.App"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App1">

    <Application.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="buttonStyle1">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Yellow" />
        </Style>

        <Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="buttonStyle2">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
        </Style>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

the mainpage.xaml.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;

// The Blank Page item template is documented at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=234238

namespace App1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Invoked when this page is about to be displayed in a Frame.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="e">Event data that describes how this page was reached.  The Parameter
        /// property is typically used to configure the page.</param>
        /// 
        private void EventButton(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {


        }
        protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

and the mainpage.xaml

```
<Page
    x:Class="App1.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App1"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid>
        <Button Name="ControlButton" Style="{StaticResource buttonStyle1}" Content="Button" Click="EventButton"/>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

just tell me what should i do in 
EventButton method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ControlButton.Style = Application.Current.Resources["buttonStyle2"] as Style`